# Why I can't perform the toFixed() function after the sum of 2 retrieved values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Into a JQuery script I have the following problem trying to use the **toFix()** JavaScript method on a number.

So I have the following situation:

```
var anticipoProgetto = $("#valoreAnticipo").text();
var saldoProgetto = $("#valoreSaldo").text();

var anticipoCalcolato = (saldoProgetto + anticipoProgetto);
console.log("ANTICIPO CALCOLATO: " + anticipoCalcolato);
anticipoCalcolato = anticipoCalcolato.toFixed(2);

$("#anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo").val(anticipoCalcolato);
```

The **console.log()** show:

```
ANTICIPO CALCOLATO: 2192.002200.37
```

So it means that JavaScript have correctly perform the addition.

The problem is that wehn try to perorm this line to obtain a value with only 2 decimals digits:

```
anticipoCalcolato = anticipoCalcolato.toFixed(2);
```

in the FireBug console I obtain this messagge error:

```
TypeError: anticipoCalcolato.toFixed is not a function
    anticipoCalcolato = anticipoCalcolato.toFixed(2);
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I wouldn’t assume that `2192.002200.37` is the result of a correct addition. I don’t know why you think it is.

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function returns a string. It's available for numbers, not strings. The value returned from `.text()` is always a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math is wrong because you are adding two string together, not two numbers. And he toFixed error is because you are trying to use toFixed on a string, but that ethod only exists on numbers.

Convert the strings to numbers when you read the `.text()`

```
var anticipoProgetto = parseFloat($("#valoreAnticipo").text()),
    saldoProgetto = parseFloat($("#valoreSaldo").text()),
    anticipoCalcolato = anticipoProgetto + saldoProgetto,
    fixed = anticipoCalcolato.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

@espacarello is correct, you need to cast from string to number.  It may be more to your intent to cast them as you read them.

If #valoreAnticipo is an input element, consider switching to .val() instead of .text()

```
var anticipoProgetto = parseFloat($("#valoreAnticipo").text()) || 0;
var saldoProgetto = parseFloat($("#valoreSaldo").text()) || 0;

var anticipoCalcolato = (saldoProgetto + anticipoProgetto);
console.log("ANTICIPO CALCOLATO: " + anticipoCalcolato);
anticipoCalcolato = anticipoCalcolato.toFixed(2);

$("#anticipoModaleUlterioreSaldo").val(anticipoCalcolato);
```