# Why when I try to sum these parseFloat() values I obtain the concatenation and not the mathematical sum?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new in JavaScript and jQuery and I am finding the following problem trying to perform a simple sum.

So I have the following situation:

```
var anticipoCalcolato = (saldoProgetto + anticipoProgetto);
anticipoCalcolato = parseFloat(anticipoCalcolato).toFixed(2);

var ulterioreSaldo = $("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").val();     
ulterioreSaldo = parseFloat(ulterioreSaldo);

var totalePagamento =  anticipoCalcolato + ulterioreSaldo;

console.log("ANTICIPO RICALCOLATO: " + anticipoCalcolato + " ULTERIORE SALDO: " + ulterioreSaldo + " TOTALE PAGAMENTO: " + totalePagamento);
```

So a you an see I am trying to sum these 2 values named **anticipoCalcolato** and **ulterioreSaldo** into the **totalePagamento** variable.

As you can see I have done a `parseFloat()` on each of the summed value.

The problem is that I obtain the following result in the FireBug console:

```
TOTALE PAGAMENTO: 4392.378.36
```

So the problem is that it seems that it still see these values as String and do the concatenation instead the sum
What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Hint: `toFixed` returns a string.

Comment: Just like your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995346), you are adding strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see I have done a parseFloat() on each of the summed value.

Note quite - you used `parseFloat()` on the *result* of summed values. You then used `toFixed()` on it which returns a string.

You need to ensure that you're always working with numerical types when you want to use mathematical operators. To that end, it's best to only use `toFixed()` at the point (or just before) the variable will be displayed to the user. Try this:

```
var anticipoCalcolato = parseFloat(saldoProgetto) + parseFloat(anticipoProgetto);
var ulterioreSaldo = parseFloat($("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").val());
var totalePagamento = (anticipoCalcolato + ulterioreSaldo).toFixed(2);

console.log("ANTICIPO RICALCOLATO: " + anticipoCalcolato + " ULTERIORE SALDO: " + ulterioreSaldo + " TOTALE PAGAMENTO: " + totalePagamento);
```

Answer (score 1):

toFixed() returns string that's why you are not getting the sum.
Kindly visit below link for more details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
var anticipoCalcolato = parseFloat(saldoProgetto) + parseFloat(anticipoProgetto);

var ulterioreSaldo    = parseFloat($("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").val());

var totalePagamento   = anticipoCalcolato + ulterioreSaldo;

console.log("ANTICIPO RICALCOLATO: " + anticipoCalcolato + " ULTERIORE SALDO: " + ulterioreSaldo + " TOTALE PAGAMENTO: " + totalePagamento);
```

Comment: while this code may work...without an explanation it is a very low quality answer, regardless of how good the code is